# Book recommendation for Model Theory

Tags: reference-request, model-theory, book-recommendation

I want to start learning model theory for my master's thesis, but I can't find the right book for me. For some context, last year as an undergrad I had a class on logic where we learned the following: [image: 1]

So I already had contact with formal languages, structures, models, and both the semantic and syntactic aspects of first-order logic and now I want to follow from this and start learning some real Model theory.

I started using David Marker's "Model Theory. An Introduction" but I'm personally not a big fan of that book: It's full of typos and I don't like how informal some of his proofs and expositions are, for example, this definition: [image]

Do you have some recommendations for a rigorous book/resources to learn Model theory, ideal for someone with a little background on the subject?

Comment: hi Eduardo; I will make one brief remark, which is that the very informal style presented in that snippet is very much not characteristic of the rest of the book! the kinds of deduction systems being referred to there are not relevant for the subject of model theory, which is why I imagine Marker chose to be quite informal with that discussion. pages 33 and 34 have a very different tone from the rest of the book :)

Comment: Well, if you say so, I'll give the book another chance. However, I'd still appreciate it if you have any other book recommendations for me to check. @AtticusStonestrom

Comment: I'm happy to share my own personal experience! however I don't have a very wide-ranging knowledge of the "canonical" introductory textbooks, so probably you will get better insight from others. but I personally learned model theory first from Marker's book and then from Tent and Ziegler's. I think Tent and Ziegler is generally more terse than Marker, but you may prefer that if you don't enjoy a "conversational" style. Tent and Ziegler also has the advantage that it goes quite a bit further within model theory than Marker does, so it's well-suited for later study too